# $L:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear map and $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface invariant under $L$, what and why is $L(S)\subset S$?

Tags: differential-geometry

$L:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear map and $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface invariant under $L$, that is $L(S)\subset S$.

My first doubt is what does $L(S)\subset S$ actually mean? Does it mean the set of points of $L(S)$ is a subset of the set of points of $S$?

My next question is why is $L(S)\subset S$? Why not $L(S)=S$? Since it is invariant that means it does not change under $L$?

Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: $L(S)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 : \;\text{there exists $y\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L(y)=x$} \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So $L(S)\subset S$ means this subset is contained in $S$. For invariance, in maths invariance property is usually defined as such, not requiring $L(S)=S$ necessarily. Often requiring $L(S)=S$ is too strong so that the condition can be relaxed a bit. Key thing we need is that anything in $L(S)$ is also in $S$, and that's all we need.

Answer (score 1):

**Tautological answer**; This is the definition.

**Illustrative answer**; Recall the notion of *invariant subspaces* in linear algebra. Again the definition is $\mathcal{W}\leq\mathcal{V}$ is an invariant subspace for the operator $T:\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{V}$ if $T(\mathcal{W})\leq \mathcal{W}$. For example, consider the linear projection on to the $xy$-plane $P_{xy}:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ written in terms of the standard basis as $P_x = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}$. The invariant subspaces here are any of $\text{span}\{e_x\},\text{span}\{e_y\}, \text{span}\{e_x,e_y\}$. Now this doesn't actually provide any motivation for why we don't restric thte definition of invariant subspace to $T(\mathcal{W}) = \mathcal{W}$ but perhaps the following alternate definition might shed light as to why the equality is too restrictive:

- $\mathcal{W}\leq\mathcal{V}$ is an invariant subspace for the linear operator $T:\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{V}$ if the restriction $T_{|\mathcal{W}}$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{W}$.